# Sending notification to Apple Watch extension

Tags: ios, iphone, bluetooth, notifications, watchkit

I have got an **iPhone** 8.2 app that **communicates** with a **bluetooth accessory** during background mode (I enabled it on the capabilities tab). Whenever I receive a message from the accessory (handled in the iPhone app bundle) I'd like to **send a notification to the Apple Watch extension** (so that the user can visualise the updated state of the accessory).

How can I do this?

---

**Additional sub-questions**:

- Ideally I'd like the user to see the notification also if the Apple
  Watch app extension is in background mode (**question 2:** can apple
  watch extension go in background mode?).
- I am also unsure if I can send a notification without turning that
  Apple watch app on. **question 3:** Is this possible?

Answer (score 4):

You can send that notification using [MMWormhole](https://github.com/mutualmobile/MMWormhole).

You send it using:

```
[self.wormhole passMessageObject:@{@"titleString" : title} 
                      identifier:@"messageIdentifier"];
```

and you receive it using:

```
[self.wormhole listenForMessageWithIdentifier:@"messageIdentifier" 
 listener:^(id messageObject) {
    // Do Something
}];
```

Note that wormhole uses app groups to communicate, so you need to enable it.

What MMWormhole uses, under the hood, is `CFNotificationCenterGetDarwinNotifyCenter` and you have more info about that [in this medium post](https://medium.com/@saberjack/ios-sending-notifications-between-your-apps-3fe7422d6a41%20.).

As for the sub-questions I am afraid I don't have 100% certain, but I believe that yes, you the apple watch extension also works in background mode. As for the third question, I didn't understand it.

Comment: I would prefer not to use a third party library. Could you edit your answer to highlight only the official Apple solution?

Comment: As far as I know apple doesn't have an official way to send notifications to your apple watch. What MMWormhole uses, under the hood, is `CFNotificationCenterGetDarwinNotifyCenter` and you have more info about that here - https://medium.com/@saberjack/ios-sending-notifications-between-your-apps-3fe7422d6a41 . MMWormhole has 250 lines of code. You can base your solution on it :)

Comment: It worth noting that there's no way to "wake up" your WatchKit app from your iOS app. Wormhole/Darwin notifications will only work instantly if the app is already open.

Comment: Thanks for the link and answer. The 3rd question means "can you actually send a notification from the iPhone App to the Watch Extension app without switching the watch extension app on?

Comment: @Bgilham I saw that WatchKit supports notifications UI elements. How does Apple intend us to use them? I mean, is there any sample of code that demonstrate how I can for example update my GPS coordinates on the Watch Kit extension glances using data deriving from the iPhone GPS?

Comment: I have no idea how notifications will be. I expect them to be reproduced in both the iPhone and apple watch at the same time. As for the glance you can update it when the app is opened in the iphone, but I am not sure you can update it when the app is not in the foreground/background. What I have tried to do in my glance was to be sure it can perform without the iphone, so the user doesn't have a blank screen every time it opens it (I am expecting that the glance is always available and you can't hide it/show it depending if the app is open/closed)

Answer (score 0):

An update for iOS 9.0 and above.

While MMWormhole works on watchOS 2 as well, it would be preferable to use Apple's [WatchConnectivity](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/WatchConnectivity/Reference/WatchConnectivity_framework/index.html) framework on watchOS 2.0 and above. MMWormhole requires the use of App Groups, while `WatchConnectivity` does not. `WatchConnectivity` does indeed require iOS 9.0 and above.

Below is a quick example of how to send a simple `String` from an iOS app to a WatchKit Extension. First let's set up a helper class.

```
class WatchConnectivityPhoneHelper : NSObject, WCSessionDelegate
{
    static let sharedInstance:WatchConnectivityPhoneHelper = WatchConnectivityPhoneHelper()
    
    let theSession:WCSession = WCSession.defaultSession()

    override init()
    {
        super.init()
        
        // Set the delegate of the WCSession
        theSession.delegate = self
        
        // Activate the session so that it will start receiving delegate callbacks
        theSession.activateSession()
    }

    // Used solely to initialize the singleton for the class, which calls the constructor and activates the event listeners
    func start()
    {
    
    }

    // Both apps must be active to send a message
    func sendStringToWatch(message:String, callback:[String : AnyObject] -> ())
    {
        // Send the message to the Watch
        theSession.sendMessage(["testString" : message], replyHandler:
        { (reply: [String : AnyObject]) -> Void in
            // Handle the reply here
            
            // Send the reply in the callback
            callback(reply)
        },
        errorHandler:
        { (error:NSError) -> Void in
            // Handle the error here
            
        })
    }

    // A message was sent by the Watch and received by the iOS app. This does NOT handle replies to messages sent from the iOS app
    func session(session: WCSession, didReceiveMessage message: [String : AnyObject], replyHandler: ([String : AnyObject]) -> Void)
    {
        // Handle received message logic here
            
        if (message["testString"] != nil)
        {
            replyHandler(["testString" : "Received Message!"])
        }
    }
}
```

This helper class would be almost identical for the WatchKit Extension. I've named the WatchKit Extension version of this class `WatchConnectivityExtensionHelper`. I won't paste it because, again, it is just about identical to the helper class above.

### Usage

We need to start the iOS and WatchKit Extension message listeners by instantiating the singleton helper class. All we need to do is call some function or refer to some variable within the singleton to initialize it. Otherwise, iOS or the WatchKit Extension will be sending out messages but the other might not receive them.

**iOS - AppDelegate.swift**

```
@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate
{
    var window: UIWindow?

    func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool
    {
        // Start the event listener for communications between the iOS app and the Apple Watch
        WatchConnectivityPhoneHelper.sharedInstance().start()

        ...
    }

    ...
}
```

**WatchKit Extension - ExtensionDelegate.swift**

```
class ExtensionDelegate: NSObject, WKExtensionDelegate
{
    func applicationDidFinishLaunching()
    {
        // Start the event listener for communications between the iOS app and the Apple Watch
        WatchConnectivityExtensionHelper.sharedInstance.start()

        ...
    }

    ...
}
```

Then anywhere in your iOS app, call `sendStringToWatch` to send a `String` to the WatchKit Extension:

```
WatchConnectivityPhoneHelper.sharedInstance.sendStringToWatch("Test message!")
{ (reply:[String : AnyObject]) -> Void in
    if (reply["testString"] != nil)
    {
        let receivedString:String = reply["testString"] as! String
                
        print(receivedString)
    }
}
```